# AngularJS Jasmine Unit Tests Select - getting option at index x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

On the angular site the have the following example of a unit test:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
(note that you need to click the protractor.js button; there is no direct link to show the unit test code)

here is the snippet of interest:

```
element.all(by.select('color')).first().click();
element.all(by.css('select[ng-model="color"] option')).first().click();
```

Is there a way to get an element other than the "first()" when using "element.all()"?
I can't seem to find proper documentation on what can be done.

Comment: I might just misunderstand you, but do you just want `element.all(...).get(x).click()`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also add a `n-th` selector to the query. Again, assuming this is the question.

Comment: element.all(...).get(x).click() exactly, or whatever the syntax may be for something of the sort

Comment: Judging by [this part of the source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L290) exactly that code (`get(x)`) should work. Did you try it? The documentation of the method also has an example which is exactly what I said above.

Comment: ok, thanks! Unfortunately i can't set your comments as an answer to the question. I was looking like crazy for that documentation in the angular documentation and searching in google. I didn't know it was a separate library.

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

Judging by [this part of the source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L290) exactly that code (get(x)) should work. Did you try it? The documentation of the method also has an example which is exactly what I said above.